# Can two parties sign each other's certificate and exchange without CA?

Tags: tls, certificates, certificate-authority

Is possible (and practical) for two users to create their own self-signed SSL certificates, exchange these certificates (perhaps in a face-to-face meeting), and then communicate with each other securely (e.g. S/MIME)? No CA involved here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and even common for two parties to exchange public key certificates of many types, without the involvement of a third party, to mutually encrypt their communication. This private exchange is the basis of the [Web of trust](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_of_trust) (WOT) decentralized authentication model. The most well-known WOT system is [Pretty Good Privacy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy) (PGP) and its variants. If each party trusts the other sufficiently to maintain the security level (authorization to access resources) being granted, the WOT model is appropriate. See also [Self-signed certificates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-signed_certificate).

[Public Key Infrastructure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure) (PKI) is the centralized authentication model used in commercial and government communications, involving a [Certificate Authority](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority) (CA) whose purpose is to vouch for the identity of the certificate bearer by performing a certain level of due diligence on the requesting entity. The request is usually delivered as a [Certificate Signing Request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_signing_request) (CSR)).

Note that there are different levels of certification authority; a number of intermediate CAs could exist between the "root" authority and the final certificate. Some organizations, especially in government and academia, maintain their own PKI root (an internal CA) which issues certificates only within the organization. What separates a "Trusted" root CA from an untrusted one is primarily root certificate installed base. Operating systems, browsers and other applications are bundled with a selection of root certificates for CAs determined to be trustworthy by the vendor or general industry consensus. Certificates issued by these CAs are automatically trusted by the software which contains them, and these certificates are often installed to the local user's keystore, allowing every application the user runs to trust them.

The two models are designed for different levels of trust. Among friends or a private organization, WOT is enough. When dealing with large numbers of people, many of whom are strangers or possible threats, PKI is preferred.

Comment: Thanks - great and thorough answer. Now I'd like to know how to implement signed/encrypted message passing between two such parties in an app I'm writing. Peer to peer.. no servers involved. Just need an API that says sign this message w private key, encrypt w other party's public key, and send to the other party. App reads by checking signature w other's public key and decrypts w private key.